# Error when saving PFQuery result

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, parse-platform, subclass

I have an **Item ViewController** with a button to create a chatRoom with the Owner of the Item.

```
-(void)createChatRoom
{

    PFQuery *queryForChatRoom = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ChatRoom"];
    [queryForChatRoom whereKey:@"user1" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [queryForChatRoom whereKey:@"user2" equalTo:self.Item.Owner];

    PFQuery *queryForChatRoomInverse = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ChatRoom"];
    [queryForChatRoomInverse whereKey:@"user1" equalTo:self.Item.Owner];
    [queryForChatRoomInverse whereKey:@"user2" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

    PFQuery *combinedChatRoomQuery = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[queryForChatRoom, queryForChatRoomInverse]];

    [combinedChatRoomQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if ([objects count] == 0){

            PFChatRoom *ChatRoom = [PFChatRoom objectWithClassName:@"ChatRoom"];
            [ChatRoom setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"user1"];
            [ChatRoom setObject:self.Item.Owner forKey:@"user2"];
            [ChatRoom saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ItemToChatSegue" sender:nil];
            }];
        }
    }];

}
```

When I press the button to execute this code I get an error occurring on any thread from 3, 4, 14, 34 on any given run.

```
[PFUser(Private) checkSaveParams]
```

I can log to the console both my [PFUser currentUser] and this ViewController's Item.Owner, so there are objects to work with. And if I try the code without the second user, I can in fact save to Parse chatRoom object with only the [PFUser currentUser] attached to it.

What do I need to do to be able to add the non-current user to this chatRoom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons, Parse won't allow your second user to be modified by the current user. If you want to be able to make changes for the second user, you need to use Cloud Code to get around this roadblock.

I have had multiple problems like this before, and every time I've been forced to use a workaround via Cloud Code.

Here's an example of a workaround I did for creating a friends relationship between two users:

```
[PFCloud callFunction:@"editUser" withParameters:@{@"userId": user.objectId}];
```

The above code statement is in xcode, and executes the function I have added to my Cloud Code file.

Then, here's what my Cloud Code file looks like:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('editUser', function(request, response) {
    var userId = request.params.userId;

    var User = Parse.Object.extend('_User'),
        user = new User({ objectId: userId });

    var currentUser = request.user;

    var relation = user.relation("friendsRelation");
    relation.add(currentUser);

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    user.save().then(function(user) {
        response.success(user);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error)
    });
});
```

The above code uses the master key to save changes to both the currently logged in user, and to the user who's objectId was passed into this function.

Code details:

```
var relation
```

This is just a variable I'm creating to hold what the following fucntion returns:

```
user.relation("friendsRelation");
```

In the above function, `"friendsRelation"` is the name of my PFRelation key in Parse.

Now that we have a valid relation object contain in our variable called `relation`, we execute this function with an argument of our `currentUser` object.

After that, all that's left is saving everything. I don't program with javascript, but I was still able to come up with the above solution by looking at the Parse Cloud Code docs, and searching around on their support forums.

If you take my template from above, and make some small changes based on what type of Parse objects you are actually working with e.g. `ChatRoom`, then you should be able to easily accomplish what you need. You just have to jump through these extra hoops because the Parse SDK doesn't want a situation where someone can login and somehow make changes to another user's account, whether by their own fault or a developer's mistake.

Comment: what exactly are you doing to get around this?
as in, what within cloud code are you modifying?

Comment: I just added an edit to my post with some details. You need to use the master key to be able to save changes to a user that is not currently logged in and authenticated.

Comment: I understand the part where you extend the Parse User object and create a new instance

but when you have

    var relation = user.relation("friendsRelation");
    relation.add(currentUser);

What is going on here? Did you define relation as a PFObject?